# call local storage using changing variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hello I am currently working on a script where I want to save table data that is appended through input text and is custom depending on the users selections.

What I want to do is save that table data as a variable that the user selects using the input where he can name the specific table data he creates.

Here is my html for the table and the other important buttons:

```
<label for="loadTask">Load Task:</label>
<label for="taskName">Task Name:</label>
<select id="loadTask" ></select>
<input type="text" id="taskName"></input>
<button type="submit" id="addTask">Add</button>
```

I would add my table html but I feel that its irrelevant to this question.

What I want to do is.. when the user wants to save his table data  he uses the taskName input and names what he would want the table data to be saved as and then he presses the addTask button which saves the data by stringify-ing it.

I then want the saved data to appear in another html page into a html select where the user can select which table data he wants to use. As well as add it into the Load Task select where the user can load the task and edit it if he wants to.

Here is what I tried already with my JS.

```
$(function() {
    $("#addTask").click(function() {
        let cells = Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementById("items-table").rows, row => {
            return Array.prototype.map.call(row.cells, cell => cell.innerHTML);
    });

        taskName = $("#taskName").val();
        localStorage.setItem(taskName, JSON.stringify(cells));
        alert("Task has been Added");
    });
});
```

then in the other html page I tried:

```
$(function() {
    var cells = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(taskName) || "[]");

    $("#select-task").append('<option>'+cells+'></option>')
})
```

but this clearly did not work because it was unable to recognize the taskName.

How would I change this script or what should I add so that I will be able to save table data as the name written into the taskName input and have the name show up in the html select so the user can select which table data he wants to use and will remember which tasks each one is because they are saved under what he named them.

also how would I append the cells so I could delete all the table data therefore removing the task from all the selects. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
var tasky = loadTaskFromStorage1($("#loadTask").val());
$("#items-table").append(tasky.cells);

if ((tasky.cells[1][1]) = "") {
    delete savedTask[taskName]
}
```

I even tried changing the variable loadTaskFromStorage because I called it in another JS html file but it still doesn't work

am I not able to call localStorage in the same file that I called it?

Any Help is appreciated Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a list of `taskName` you should get all of them from `localStorage`. But there is some objects that you would not consider as task. My suggestion is to keep tasks in a new object (or an array) on the `localStorage` and inquire it from this object.

```js
$(function () {

    // Load all tasks from storage and fill the tasks dropdown
    loadAllTasks();

    $("#addTask").click(function () {
        let cells = Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementById("items-table").rows, row => {
            return Array.prototype.map.call(row.cells, cell => cell.innerHTML);
        });

        // create task object from cells
        var task = { cells: cells };

        // set name property of the task
        task.Name = $("#taskName").val();

        // call save method using the new task object
        saveTaskInStorage(task);
    });
});


function saveTaskInStorage(task) {
    // Get stored object from localStorage
    var savedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));

    // To be sure that object exists on localStorage
    if (!savedTasks || typeof (savedTasks) !== "object")
        savedTasks = {};

    // Set the new or exists task by the task name on savedTasks object
    savedTasks[task.Name] = task;

    // Stringify the savedTasks and store in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(savedTasks));

    alert("Task has been Added");
}

function loadAllTasks() {

    // Get all saved tasks from storage and parse json string to javascript object
    var savedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));

    // To be sure that object exists on localStorage
    if (!savedTasks || typeof (savedTasks) !== "object")
        return;

    // Get all property name of savedTasks object (here it means task names)
    for (var taskName in savedTasks){
        $("#select-task").append('<option>' + taskName + '></option>')
    }
}

function loadTaskFromStorage(taskName) {
    var savedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));

    // Return the task by its name (property name on savedTasks object)
    return savedTasks[taskName];
}
```

You can also use `loadTaskFromStorage(taskName)` to load a task by its name. For example:

```
var task = loadTaskFromStorage($("#select-task").val());
```

Comment: I tried var task = loadTaskFromStorage($("#select-task").val());   then I tried alert(task[1][0]);   for it to alert the second row and the first cell and it said "cannot read 0 of undefined"

Comment: becuase before I was able to localstorage the cells then I could call cells[1][0] and it alerted me the first table data cell that I inputed

Comment: and also be able to select a task and then append all the cells into the table so then I could delete them all and if the table is empty then it removes the task and its taskName from all the selects

Comment: Please try **task.cells[1][0]** instead of **task[1][0]**. It's because of the object that I've written on save function (something like this: { taskName: '', cells: {} }).

Comment: just one more quick question sorry for bothering you again. How would I make it append all the tasks depending on which select task I choose so I can delete all the table data inside the specified task then if the task table data is empty to just remove the taskName from all the selects essentially just deleting the task (taskName)

Comment: something like this??                           var task = loadTaskFromStorage($("#loadTask").val());
$("#items-table").append(task.cells);

if ((task.cells) = "") 
 storage.removeItem(task)    this does not work I have tried it    ( am I able to call the var tasky = loadTaskFromStorage($("#loadTask").val());     but just changing the loadTask to select-Task or will that not work becuase I am having trouble with it

Comment: You can use `delete` operator. For example: `delete savedTask[taskName]`.
This code removes the given `taskName` from `savedTasks` object.

Comment: Thank you for helping me I am still kind of struggling on How I would append all the saved table data back in the table when I select it in the loadTask html select   How would I do this  I am trying to loadTaskFromStorage with the select val and it says that task is undefined and I tried changing the variable and it still doesn't work